# system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait not working when window is maximize

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I am sending keystrokes to other running application by using `SendKeys.SendWait`. But it is not working if the target application is not minimize. Is anything wrong with this method? What are the other methods to send keystrokes to running application.

Code Block that I am using:

```
SetForegroundWindow(handleToApplication);            
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(Keystroke);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest manipulating the Window prior to sending the Keys to it...

```
    private void setWindowState(string windowTitle, int option)
    {
        /**
        SW_HIDE             0
        SW_SHOWNORMAL       1
        SW_NORMAL           1
        SW_SHOWMINIMIZED    2
        SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED    3
        SW_MAXIMIZE         3
        SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE   4
        SW_SHOW             5
        SW_MINIMIZE         6
        SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE  7
        SW_SHOWNA           8
        SW_RESTORE          9
        SW_SHOWDEFAULT      10
        SW_FORCEMINIMIZE    11
        SW_MAX              11
        **/

        Process[] plist = Process.GetProcesses();
        IntPtr handle = new IntPtr();

        foreach (Process x in plist)
        {
            if (x.MainWindowTitle == windowTitle)
            {
                handle = x.MainWindowHandle;
                break;
            }
        }

        ShowWindow(handle, option);
    }
```